# numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares on first run only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been wrestling with a known and documented SVD converge issue. Having read up on similar issues raised by others, I have double checked my data and reduced this to a tiny DataFrame - 10 rows/2 columns only - both float64's. There are definitely no NaN or infinities.

On first run, I pause at the offending line via breakpoint. First time I manually execute the next (offending) line i get a console error (see below) - but on subsequent runs it resolves without errors!! I am using numpy 1.19.1

I would greatly appreciate thoughts or ideas on how to resolve this. It is driving me nuts and its shaken my confidence.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. I really want to get to the bottom of this.

Luthor

The code:

```
# Simplifying the df
df = df.head(10)
df = df[['dti','close']]
print(df)
ltt2_poly = np.polyfit(df['dti'] - df['dti'][0], df['close'], 2)
```

At runtime:

```
pydev debugger: process 36368 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.6948.78)
Importing local settings
   dti  close
0    0  11.28
1    3  11.35
2    4  11.10
3    5  10.95
4    6  11.07
5    7  11.45
6   10  11.46
7   11  11.46
8   12  11.74
9   13  11.96

**ltt2_poly = np.polyfit(df['dti'] - df['dti'][0], df['close'], 2)**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in polyfit
  File "C:\Users\luthor\PycharmProjects\MC\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 629, in polyfit
    c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in lstsq
  File "C:\Users\luthor\PycharmProjects\MC\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2306, in lstsq
    x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\luthor\PycharmProjects\MC\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 100, in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

*In the SAME debug session:*

**ltt2_poly = np.polyfit(df['dti'] - df['dti'][0], df['close'], 2)**    now works!!!

print(ltt2_poly)
[ 1.00902938e-02 -8.70161869e-02  1.13247743e+01]
```

print(np.**version**)
1.19.1

To add insult to injury, when I reduce the df to between 5-9 - it works without the failure. What am I missing??

Comment: So literally - executing the same np.polyfit(df['dti'] - df['dti'][0], df['close'], 2) again works when the first try result sin a SVD error ...

A bit of additional info - my initial attempt was in PyCharm but I get the identical result in vscode ... on a separate PC (to rule out environmentals).

I really would like to understand the cause!

Comment: Subsequently also tried numpy version 1.19.2 - no joy yet. Any recommendations to get tot he root cause would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I tried 1.18.0 as someone suggested below and then tried all 1.19 releases besides 1.19.4 where they currently are experiencing some problems. The only release that didn't raise this error was 1.19.3. I can't find any explanation regarding why this happens. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a solution to that, but I can tell you that you're not alone. I have the same bug.

I "fixed" it by simply wrapping the NumPy function in a while-try statement.

while True:
try:
NumPy-function
break
except:
continue

Comment: Thanks - but that is actually quite sad. I love the richness of numpy and the thought of not being able to rely on it to produce consistent output is concerning. I hope there is going to be an outcome here - and hopefully it is me not getting it right!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a conda environment with numpy 1.18

This version seems to predate these kinds of errors and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of two things:

1. Numpy and Scipy use LAPACK gesdd as the default way to compute the SVD.  This is usually faster, but less stable than gesvd.  If gesdd fails, try

```
scipy.linalg.svd(A,lapack_driver="gesvd")
```

2. Failure of the SVD to converge when the matrix involve has no NaN or Inf values may indicate that NumPy is using a buggy (old) version of BLAS/LAPACK. (see [Why does interp1d throw LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269325/why-does-interp1d-throw-linalgerrorsvd-did-not-converge))

On my Ubuntu machine I was able to fix this by reinstalling BLAS and LAPACK

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev python-dev
```

and reinstalling numpy

```
pip install --force-reinstall numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code may lead to exactly this non-convergence error:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearRegression())
pipe.fit(trainingDf, ySer)
```

This happens on rare occasions, even when the data does not contain Nan or infinite data points. However, as soon as I removed the normalization, the code runs fine:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_std=False), LinearRegression())
pipe.fit(trainingDf, ySer)
```

Similar in the past before pipelines with:

```
regr = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
regr.fit(XDf.to_numpy(),ySer.to_numpy())
```

and:

```
regr = LinearRegression(normalize=False)
regr.fit(XDf.to_numpy(),ySer.to_numpy())
```