# Python - LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares - no Nans or infs in data

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([0.5  , 0.505, 0.51 , 0.515, 0.52 , 0.525, 0.53 , 0.535, 0.54 ,
       0.545, 0.55 , 0.555, 0.56 , 0.565, 0.57 , 0.575, 0.58 , 0.585,
       0.59 , 0.595])
b = np.array([ 49.62358846,  50.21487603,  53.03564434,  51.68435625,
        53.25301205,  54.04002965,  54.97835498,  52.83363803,
        59.1954023 ,  59.82532751,  60.33057851,  56.16438356,
        53.33333333,  72.22222222,  51.72413793,  41.66666667,
        33.33333333,  44.44444444,  25.        , 100.        ])

np.polyfit(a, b, 1)
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes it does and throws the below error. Can anybody repeat this or does anybody have any clue what is going on? It should never throw an error with data as nice as this.

```
*LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-d8db33e4c692> in <module>
----> 1 np.polyfit(a, b, 1)

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\other\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    627     scale = NX.sqrt((lhs*lhs).sum(axis=0))
    628     lhs /= scale
--> 629     c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
    630     c = (c.T/scale).T  # broadcast scale coefficients
    631 

<__array_function__ internals> in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\other\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2304         # lapack can't handle n_rhs = 0 - so allocate the array one larger in that axis
   2305         b = zeros(b.shape[:-2] + (m, n_rhs + 1), dtype=b.dtype)
-> 2306     x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   2307     if m == 0:
   2308         x[...] = 0

C:\ProgramData\other\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag)
     98 
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag):
--> 100     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
    101 
    102 def get_linalg_error_extobj(callback):

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares*
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. Possibly more detail in the example would help. See here for ideas about what else to include: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: SVD is very suspicious here

Comment: Are you running on Windows 10, update 2004?  See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16744

Answer (score -1):

I found exactly the same problem posted here:
[numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares on first run only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761366/numpy-linalg-linalgerror-svd-did-not-converge-in-linear-least-squares-on-first)

And since then run into the same issue again doing a Data Science learning course. If you run that exact same piece of code again it will work ... There are valid reasons why there would be no convergence such as NaNs etc - but there seems to be a genuine issue in SVD as pointed out by the Mad Scientist.